# Firefox addon or similar tool to "hack" login cookies to keep me logged in?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, auto-login

I'm getting extremely tired of having to log into websites. Are there any addons or tools that exist that will keep altering my cookie expiration for sites I choose to keep making the expiration far into the future?

Comment: I find some irony in my posting of this, after installing Cookie Manager to edit the auth cookies I see that they have tracking cookies put on my computer which expire in 2038. So remember me site login, short; unasked for tracking cookies, infinity. Excellent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cookie manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cookies-manager-plus/) will allow you to edit cookies and change the expiration date on them.  A second add on is [Add and Edit cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/add-n-edit-cookies/).  As suggested in the other answer, some cookies may have expiration dates set on the server but you should be able to change most of them.

Comment: Is there a feature disparity between Cookie Manager and Add and Edit cookies or are they similar features just different tools?

Comment: Same same really, I use cookie manager and it works fine.

Comment: It'd be nice if it had some kind of support to write rules for sites to boost cookie expiration automatically, but assuming they're not including the ticket expiration encrypted in the cookie or on the server then I should only have to mess with my cookies for each site once for a long time.

Answer (score -2):

Some sites will store the expiration info on the server, which would mean you're out of luck.

I haven't had to log into a site (from my main PC) for a long time, except for financial sites where I'm glad they don't let me get around it. This one, YouTube, Google, Yahoo! ... none of them have expired for me for a while. Why not just use better web sites?

Comment: `Why not just use better web sites?` This statement is so asinine, I'm almost shocked to see it given. Because hosting providers, vendors, and 3rd party services websites are interchangeable rightttt.

Comment: I liked your use of asinine...

Comment: I'm a capitalist--I think competition is good. If sites don't offer the features that Mr. Marisc wants, why should he keep using them?

Comment: because they might be used by my organization? Or just because their login system is daft and "remember me" has the attention span of a gnat that what's behind the gate is best available?